# How to chose which GPU to run on with HuggingFace?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I'm working on a machine with multiple GPUs (indexed 0 to 7).

I would like to deploy and train a HuggingFace pretrained model (RoBERTa) on one of them and be able to specify on which one, say GPU number 7.

I went over [transformers library docs](https://huggingface.co/transformers/) and looked for which parameter sets the GPU index but didn't find any.

How do I set this GPUs configuration?

Comment: If the code doesn't support GPU selection (no idea if that is the case, sorry), investigate `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`. That might work for your use case